# Style QComboBox in Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qtstylesheets

I got some issues with styling the combobox popup of Qt5 in Mac OSX

my Stylesheet for QComboBox

```
QComboBox {
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px;
    border: 2px groove #4B4F4F;
    border-bottom: 2px ridge #424545;
    border-right: 2px ridge #424545;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #DEDEDE;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, x2:0, y1:0, y2:1, stop:0 #6B6E6E, stop:1 #595B5B);
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 14px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: #999999;
    border-left-style: solid; /* just a single line */
    border-top-right-radius: 3px; /* same radius as the QComboBox */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
QComboBox::down-arrow {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    image: url(:/resources/images/downarrow.png);
}
QComboBox:on {
    border: 1px solid #00A7CC;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    min-width: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid #808A8A;
    border: 1px solid #373838;
    selection-background-color: #808A8A;
    background-color: #4A4C4F;
}
QComboBox:!enabled {
    color: #909090;
}
```

The Result on Mac OSX looks like this:

[image]

The following things that i would like to change:

- Get rid of the white space on the top and bottom of the popup
- Hide the tick on the left or change the size of it

**EDIT:**

I could solve the problem with the white space but not with the tick. It still looks ugly.

I changed the padding of QComboBox to this:

```
QComboBox {
        padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
....
```

I still have a small dot in the left top corner and dont know how i can hide this

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to hide the tick too, but the solution with QStyleFactory didn't work well. So I worked around and I found another solution that did the trick for me:

```
ui->comboBox->setItemDelegate(new QStyledItemDelegate());
```

Comment: this is a better solution than using another OS style

Answer (score 1):

Adding this below line in SetStyleSheet may solve your problem, I had the same issue but now it is solved.

```
combobox-popup: 0;
```

Comment: This removes both ticks and the whitespace!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, but still not find solution, so I change the style factory:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    ui->cb_action->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"));
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with:

```
ui->cb_action->setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"));
```

... as suggested by vic-lin.